# Authorize application to use twitter ads api via OAuth2

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I'm using Python's Twython library and want to get access to Twitter Ads API. I've register application and gain app id and app secret key and also get access token. How I can authorize my own application to get access to my own Twitter Ads Campaign? I've authorized via Twython instance, but when I make a request, for example `twitter.request('https://ads-api.twitter.com/0/stats/accounts/{0}/campaigns/{1}'.format(ACCOUNT_ID, CAMPAIGN_ID))` I get 401 Error: Unauthorized. Please, help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twitter Ads API only supports OAuth 1.0A at this time. Twython and other libraries support this user-context auth method for Twitter APIs (same method used for [statuses/update](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update)), or you could use an OAuth lib directly, such as [oauth2](https://github.com/joestump/python-oauth2) -- which has a misleading name, it's actually OAuth 1.0A.

More on this:

https://twitter.com/AdsAPI/status/662626967775264768

https://dev.twitter.com/ads/overview/getting-started

Mini sample of this using Twitter APIs with OAuth 1.0A and oauth2 library is [here](https://github.com/jaakko-sf/twauth-web).